# Por que um elemento do HTML é encontrado apenas no "onload"?

Tags: javascript, dom

Se eu colocar o código livre, sem estar dentro do `onload`, a variável `button` vira `null`. Meu código atual funciona, mas queria saber o porquê de não funcionar sem estar dentro da função `onload`.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
        
        <input id="start" type="submit" value="Start">

    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
onload = function() {
    let h1 = document.getElementById("title"); 
    let button = document.getElementById("start");

    button.addEventListener("click", changeTitleText);
        
    function changeTitleText() {
        h1.innerHTML = "New Title"
    }
}
```

[image: Este é o erro que ocorre se eu colocar o código JavaScript acima fora da função Onload]

Comment: Não é somente depois do `load`. De fato, funciona porque o `load` sempre será disparado após `DOMContentLoaded`, que é o evento que marca, de fato, o momento em que o DOM pode ser manipulado.

Answer (score 2):

Fora do onload o código é executado antes do elemento
`<button>`existir.
Dentro do onload você garante que o código será executado somente quando toda a página for carregada.

Por isso se recomenda colocar os scripts ao final da pagina, antes de fechar `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

Várias ações ocorrem ao carregar uma página na internet. O HTML é baixado, entendido e renderizado pelo navegador; as imagens e folhas de estilo são baixadas e renderizadas; etc. Com JavaScript você consegue executar código que é atrelado à essas ações, chamados eventos.

O evento de `load`, em questão, é disparado no final do carregamento do documento HTML. É nesse momento que você tem a garantia de que tudo está na DOM, todas as imagens, scripts, links, e subframes carregaram. Sem o evento, você não consegue ter certeza de que o que você precisa já está lá quando seu código é executado.